# Matplotlib: When rendering eps files, what font setting on linux will be compatible MS Word (2010) on Windows?

Tags: python, matplotlib, fonts, ms-word

I am generating eps format publication figures using `matplotlib` 1.3.1-1 on Linux (Ubuntu 14.04).  I want to insert these figures in a MS Word (2010) document I am preparing on Window 7.  I can open the figures using [Evince](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Evince/Downloads) on either Linux or Windows and the figures look exactly like I want them.  When I put the figure into the word document all of the text gets lost (titles, legends, labels, etc).  If I load the figures into [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/en/) (only works on the Linux machine, don't know why Inkscape on Windows cannot load them) during the load process there is a question asking if I want to change any missing fonts.  If after loading them into Inkscape, I save a new eps file, these new files can be imported into the word document without any problems.  Consequently, I think the issue is Windows (and Inkscape) is missing the default font used in `matplotlib`. I want to avoid creating a new copy of every figure mainly because of the added time but also because the resulting math fonts do not look nice.  Has anyone else overcome this or have recommendations?

Here is an example of an original figure
[image]

Here is the result after loading then saving on Inkscape
[image]

Here is a screenshot of the original figure inserted into MS Word
[image]

As a note, the Inkscape version is 561 KB while the original is only 76 KB so perhaps Inkscape is embedding the font into the file.  Is there a way to do this using `matplotlib`?

Comment: If you need to include your figures in Word, you probably don't want to generate `eps` files. Generating bitmaps sized for the page dimensions (with print fidelity, so at least 300dpi) that your word document is using will be a much easier, and higher quality, path to victory. If you're doing science, you're not deleting the code that generates these figures because someone's going to have to at some point reproduce your work, so you'll always be able to regenerate the figures if you need to publish in a new format.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, I agree using bitmaps would be much simpler and I actually currently output both because sometime I do not have the time to muck around with the eps files.  Part of the motivation for using eps files is I want to submit eps files to the journal for print purposes (high quality at any size) and using eps files for everything means I only have to manage half the image files.  The other reason is that is the preference of the research group and the PI for I work with.

Comment: if you're submitting to a journal, I sincerely hope they don't want word files but something like .tex, for which adding .eps is a lot easier... =/ I traditionally just generate different documents for different audiences from the same base data, because it's less fiddly that way.

Comment: I am sure they accept either.  I prefer LaTeX but it is not up to me.